# foreach laravel not have result

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have problem with foreach the result of API request.

Code for get the data:

```
public function index() {

     if(!session()->has('access_token')) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }

    $accessToken = session()->get('access_token');

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', env('API_URL').'/profile_question', [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
        ],
    ]);

    return view('incompleteprofile.incompletewizard', compact(['response']));
```

Foreach:

```
@foreach ($response as $swingstatus)
    <p>{{$swingstatus->Question}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Result dump:

```
[[{"id":1,"Question":"Swing status","description":"test","gender":"male","language":"en"},{"id":4,"Question":"Swing status","description":"test5","gender":"male","language":"en"}],[{"id":5,"Question":"Searching For","description":"teererer","gender":"male","language":"nl"}],[{"id":5,"Question":"Searching For","description":"teererer","gender":"male","language":"nl"}]]
```

Result foreach in blade keep blank, can someone help me to get the data inside mine blade.

Comment: Please try `@foreach ($response[0] as $swingstatus)`

Comment: Glad to be of help, please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use this code`:

```php
@foreach ($response[0] as $swingstatus)
   <p>{{$swingstatus->Question}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Your response is an `array` with one `array` of `objects`.